# 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'latest'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I have received this error when trying to run a function. This is my first django/python project so I am not experienced in this. I have searched for this error but not found anything similar.

```
def getpriority(chunks):
    p = 0
    for chunk in chunks:
        a = chunk.result_set.all()
        l = a.latest()
        if pytz.utc.localize(datetime.now()) - l.timestamp > datetime.timedelta(days=3):
            x = getresult(chunk)
            print(x)
```

I am trying to assign priorities to my Chunk model so I can select the Chunk with the highest priority to use the object.

I believe that my error is in calling `latest()` on 'a'.

When I run Chunk.result_set.latest() in a django shell I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'latest'
```

In my Result model, I have set get_latest_by which I believe is required to run  .latest():

```
class Result(models.Model):
    rel_chunk = models.ForeignKey(Chunk, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'timestamp'
```

I believe that the error lies in the fact that I'm calling latest on a related object set but if this can't be called on a related object set then how can I find the latest related Result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be `chunk.result_set.latest()` not `Chunk.result_set.latest()`

note that `chunk` should be a instance not a class model.

Comment: `chunk.result_set` is a manager, and as such it proxies all queryset methods. There's no need for `.all()`. However, you do need to access it on an instance, not on the class `Chunk`.

Comment: @knbk yep,  I miss that, I fixed.

Answer (score 6):

The error indicates that you're accessing the `result_set` attribute on the model class. You need to access it on a model instance, in which case it will return a proper manager object instead of a `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor`:

```
chunk = Chunk.objects.get(...)
chunk.result_set.latest()
```

Here, `chunk.result_set` is a manager that behaves exactly like `Result.objects`, except it filters the queryset to only include results related to the `chunk` instance. The manager also has some added methods to manipulate the relation between `chunk` and the results, such as `chunk.result_set.add()` and `chunk.result_set.remove()` to add/remove results from the result set related to this `chunk` instance.

As this all applies to a specific *instance* of `Chunk`, it makes no sense to access the related manager on a class level. That's why you need a `Chunk` instance to use the related manager.

Since `chunk.result_set` is a manager instance, it proxies all queryset methods*. There is no reason why you would need `chunk.result_set.all().latest()` instead of just `chunk.result_set.latest()`.

<sub>*) `delete()` is disabled on managers so you don't accidentally delete all objects. `as_manager()` is disabled as it makes no sense on a manager.</sub>

Comment: well explained as well.