# ReverseManyToOneDescriptor object has no attribute order_by django 2.1

Tags: django, python-3.x, sql-order-by

im learning from the book the python crash course and i'm trying to create ids for topic here's the code:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = Topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

django raises an error when i go to http://localhost:8000/topics/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'latest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250430/reversemanytoonedescriptor-object-has-no-attribute-latest)

Comment: It should be `topic.entry_set.all().order_by(..)`.

Answer (score 3):

You used the model class instead of the instance. Replace:

```
entries = Topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
```

by

```
entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added') # lowercase "t"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting this, but I have the same issue and the above solutions don't work for me.
Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic


def index(request):
    """The home page for learning log"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')


def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)


def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')  # lowercase "t"
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have an uppercase "T" in the word topic the function topics at the line

```
topics = Topic.object.order_by('date_added')
```

, change this to lowercase as well.

```
topics = topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this : `entries = Topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')`

Try this : `entries = Topic.entry_set.all().order_by('-date_added')`